# Counting work time in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, counting

I started learning SQL and I have few problems. First of all I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE WorkTime 
(
    WorkerID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Workers(ID),
    StartTime DATETIME NOT NULL,
    EndTime DATETIME NOT NULL,
)
```

I'm trying to write a procedure to count payment based on number of hours worked in a month.

What I've got:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CountPayment
    (@data DATE, @WorkerID INT)
AS
    SELECT * 
    FROM WorkTime AS A 
    WHERE A.WorkerID = @WorkerID 
      AND MONTH(@data) = MONTH(A.StartTime)
```

And I don't know how to count number of hours.

Comment: I'm guessing this is SQL Server?  Do you know which version?  Do you have any data where `StartTime` is in one month and `EndTime` is in a different month?  If so, how would you like to handle it?  If someone works 1 hour 59 minutes and then 1 hour 1 minute, for example, would that be 3 hours?  *(What level of accuracy is your data, and what level of accuracy should be processed by your calculations?)*

Comment: You can get difference between 2 column dates  with this query, and you can do aggregation further per month. Try this `select  cast(DATEDIFF(second, EndTime, StartTime) / 3600.0 as decimal(18,2)) Hoursworked
from worktime`

Comment: I do not need to handle 'crazy' variants. It should be as simple as possible.

Comment: @JoePoe There are reasons people are asking. Not sure what a crazy variant. You to refer to hours but most payroll doesn't deal in whole hours.

Comment: @BHouse You've got those arguments backward.

Comment: You'll need to also filter on year unless you're sure there are never more than 12 months of data in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are multiple rows per month you probably want something like this:

```
sum(datediff(second, StartTime, EndTime)) / 3600.0
```

Now your method name implies it's calculating a payment when all we've done is compute a fractional number of hours. I might suggest reconsidering the name of you don't mind me saying that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full working example. This is done quickly and written for last month. If you provide more details we can assist more, this isn't something I would put into production, this is to get you started. This is built to show you how, I did not format it to fit your params, and depending on the version eomonth will not work, there are other ways to find the being and end of a month via google that will work with various version of SQL Server.

```
declare @example as table (
    ExampleID   int identity(1,1) not null primary key clustered
,   WorkerID    int not null
,   StartTime   datetime2(3) not null
,   EndTime     datetime2(3) not null
);


insert into @example (WorkerID, StartTime, EndTime)

select  10, '2018-01-19 08:15:00', '2018-01-19 13:02:00' union all
select  10, '2018-01-19 08:02:00', '2018-01-19 13:02:00' union all
select  23, '2018-01-19 07:12:00', '2018-01-19 13:02:00' union all
select  10, '2018-01-19 06:22:00', '2018-01-19 13:02:00' union all
select  55, '2018-01-19 09:32:00', '2018-01-19 13:02:00' union all
select  76, '2018-01-19 08:07:00', '2018-01-19 13:02:00' union all
select  43, '2018-01-19 10:05:00', '2018-01-19 13:02:00' union all
select  65, '2018-01-19 06:13:00', '2018-01-19 13:02:00' union all
select  98, '2018-01-19 08:18:00', '2018-01-19 13:02:00' union all
select 101, '2018-01-19 06:00:00', '2018-01-19 13:02:00' 

 ;with cte as (
    select WorkerID
         , datediff(hour, StartTime, EndTime) hours_
      from @example
     where StartTime > dateadd(day, 1, eomonth(sysdatetime(), -2))
       and EndTime < eomonth(sysdatetime(), -1) 
           )

    select WorkerID
         , sum(hours_) TotalHours
      from cte
  group by WorkerID
```